# Resample the training data before or after train a baseline model?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, hyperparameter, baseline

I'm working on an unbalanced dataset with three classes. The original proportions are:

- class 1: 48%
- class 2: 37%
- class 3: 15%

First I'm gonna train a baseline model and I would like to know if I should resample the dataset before or after the training.

Another question is about the hyper parameters of the baseline model. What to do? Tune or not?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you want to resample the data?

Comment: I second the questions from Tim, because the answer is that you [probably shouldn’t “fix” class imbalance at all](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he).

Comment: Actually yes, that's exactly what I was trying to do. I'm learning about machine learning and I know I cannot trust in 'accuracy' if the the dataset is unbalanced. There are other metrics I can use like 'precision', 'recall', but what if, despite Dave's advice, I still want to balance the dataset. What do you think I should do? Resample before or after train the baseline model? And  about the hyper parameters of it?